# Debezium MySQL parameter table.exclude.list not working

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using Debezium and MySQL. In the database there is a table managed by the Flyway and I want to exclude it. I used the configurations below:

```
name=IRS-Connector
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
database.hostname=mysql
database.port=3306
database.user=user
database.password=user
database.allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
database.server.name=irs-conn-v1
database.include.list=decider
database.exclude.list=register
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=schema-changes.decider
table.exclude.list=flyway_schema_history
```

But when I'll see the topic **irs-conn-v1.decider.flyway_schema_history** had been created.

Answer (score 1):

According the doc of the [`table.exclude.list`](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-property-table-exclude-list) option:

> Each identifier is of the form `databaseName.tableName`.

So you need to append `databaseName`:

```
table.exclude.list=decider.flyway_schema_history
```

Comment: Hello, I tried it and it didn't work either.

Comment: What's Debezium version? Is there somthing useful in logs?

Comment: I'm using Kafka with docker-compose and the landoop/kafka-lenses-dev image, I tried to get the logs but the that I founded there is not anything about the Debezium.